# How to use this jQuery to effect css opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been given a piece of jQuery that is meant to find the position of the users mouse, and the closer to the center the mouse is, the more it effects the opacity of elements on the page. The desired effect will be a fade as the mouse gets closer to the center, with a full screen logo fading to opacity: 0, the background going from black to white, and white text being revealed. Here is the code I have been given:

```
$('body').on('mousemove', function(e) {
var x_val = 2 *(e.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft()) / $(window).width() - 1,
    y_val = 2 * (e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop()) / $(window).height() - 1,
    opacity = (1 - Math.abs(x_val)) * (1 - Math.abs(y_val));

    console.log(opacity)
});
```

Now, I am quite novice at jQuery, and any advice that you could give on how to have this code effect my css in the desired way would be massively appreciated!
Merry Christmas!

Comment: did you try to google `jquery css`? Would likely have found this http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you will need to add an element in which you want to change the opacity for.

```js
  $('#body').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x_val = 2 * (e.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft()) / $(window).width() - 1,
      y_val = 2 * (e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop()) / $(window).height() - 1,
      opacity = (1 - Math.abs(x_val)) * (1 - Math.abs(y_val));
    $(".MyDiv,.something").css("opacity", opacity);
  });
```

```css
.MyDiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 150px
}
.something {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="body">
  <div class="MyDiv"></div>
  <h3 class="something">Something else</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I have got it working with your method! However I do want to be able to apply the opacity change to multiple divs, each with an id="fadeaway". I have my jQuery set to $("#fadeaway").css("opacity", opacity); but it is only applying to the first div of two. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @Scroggod If you see my edit, and re-run the code snippet, you can see i've added an extra element. You can just add extra things in like this `$(".MyDiv , .something")` like I did above. You just need to put commas in between them.

Please note, you should use `class="fadeaway"`on your elements as ID's should be unique.

Answer (score -1):

if you can see the given function returns a value as the opacity. And the function is called when the mouse is moved. `e` represent the element which the mouse is over. so take that element using the following code and set the opacity like this.

```
$(e.target).css('opacity',opacity)
```

This set's the opacity of the hovering element to the calculated value. Now there will be another problem where when mouse leave, the element will still contain the opacity which was given earlier.

So you should bind an event to the above element like this.

```
$(e.target).bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','100') ;
    $(this).unbind('mouseleave'); //this will remove unwanted event binds after mouse has left.
})
```

All of the above code should come inside your function.

Comment: please let me know what is wrong in my answer to downvote it.